# Creating a UserControl with a TextBox with databinding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a custom usercontrol in WPF, that includes a textbox and some other controls. I want to be able to bind a string property from the datacontext to my usercontrol, that is then passed on to the TextBox within my usercontrol.

If it was a regular textbox, I would do this to bind the property `FirstName` of the object in the `DataContext`:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" />`

In my `CustomTextBox`, I would like to be able to do this:

`<local:CustomTextBox CustomText="{Binding FirstName}"/>`

But I can't quite get the databinding to work.

Codebehind for my `CustomTextBox`:

```
public partial class CustomTextBox : UserControl
{
    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomTextProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                        "CustomText",
                        typeof(string),
                        typeof(CustomTextBox));

    public string CustomText
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(CustomTextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CustomTextProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml markup for `CustomTextBox`:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding CustomText}"></TextBox> 
</Grid>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I got it working, thanks to the duped question - I guess you had to know that it is called TwoWay binding, in order to be able to search for a solution.

Comment: Note that you can register the CustomText property with `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`.

Comment: @Clemens, Thanks. Do I add it in the same `DependencyProperty` that I already have for the `Text` property? `public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(CustomTextBox), null);`

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42397657/1136211